# how can i add "between" in a switch case statement like this

Tags: mysql, switch-statement

i have a table that captures daily transactions with date_captured as the date  column in my db i want to use that date to check what took place within a month. e.g from my input field date1=2020-02-01 and date2=2020-02-30

i want to output from db:
 1. user bought bread 2020-02-03
 2. user bought butter 2020-02-15

i tired with this code below but still find cant my way round it, please someone help!!!

```
$queryCondition = "";
  if(!empty($_POST["search"])) {
    foreach($_POST["search"] as $k=>$v){
      if(!empty($v)) {

        $queryCases = array("this","that","date1","date2");
       if(in_array($k,$queryCases)) {
          if(!empty($queryCondition)) {
            $queryCondition .= " AND ";
          } else {
            $queryCondition .= " WHERE ";
          }
        }

        switch($k) {
          case "this":
            $this= $v;
            $queryCondition .= "allp LIKE '%" . mysql_prep($v) . "%'";
            break;
          case "that":
            $that= $v;
            $queryCondition .= "notp LIKE '" . mysql_prep($v) . "%'";
            break;
            case "date1":
            case "date2":
            $date1= $v;
            $date2= $j;
            $queryCondition .= "date_captured BETWEEN " . $v . " AND date_captured " . $j . "";
            break;
        }
      }
    } 
  }

  $orderby = " ORDER BY patient_id asc"; 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable" . $queryCondition ;
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you want.  One way to do this is to describe what your input is and explain the output you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Hey Robert , i just edited it, is it clear enough?

Comment: *i want* Where do you want to do this - on the MySQL side or in PHP script?

Comment: @Akina  PHP script i mean

Comment: If so I'm off...